# City of the dead puzzle room

Tags: darksiders-2

In the city of the dead, I pushed the floating platform in the pit of spikes where there is a lever on the wall, How do I get the floating platform out of the spikes, and am I stuck for good?

Comment: Please reference the previous question of "How do I get past this puzzle in the City of the Dead?" for more details.  I may have found a glitch in the game......not sure how to fix this!!!

Comment: You're not supposed to be able to do that i believe, isn't there a ledge in front of the pit with spikes ? In either case, your best bet will be to reload a previous save

Comment: Somehow I managed to push the platform in the spikes!  I can't believe the creators of the game would allow this loop hole to exist.  I am really upset to undo all that I have accomplished.

Comment: i have the same problem here my friend.. and i just figured out that the platforms right place isnt the hole with the spikes.. ive already managed to move the platform INSIDE the by deathgriping while falling into the spikes but.. i cant take the platform OFF the hole..
please guys give us something useful.... my last saved game was after doing this..

Answer (score 1):

Use the deaths grip ability. You cam grab the platform from a distance and pull it back to you.

Comment: Have you tried this to see if it works? The pit is quite deep and i'd be suprised, depending on how deep the platform fell into the pit, you're able to pull out the platform with Deathgrip.

Comment: I appreciate your advice and comments but the platform is submerged in the corner of the pit.  I try to use the grip ability and it doesn't budge at all.  The only saved game I could load was after the fact of the platform getting stuck in the pit.  I was a huge darksider fan but after what happened to me, will never play the game again!!!!